# Match multiple columns with Laravel eloquent or query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Match two tables based on multiple column match with laravel.

I have two tables,lets say results and answers.

```
actual_result
        id|question_id|score1|score2
user_answers
        id|question_id|score1|score2
```

Now how can i get list of all records preferably with eloquent where scores fields of both the tables are matched ?
In other words how i can get list of answers which are correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INNER JOIN` and can choose multiple column as JOIN SELECTOR.

Example Query

```
SELECT * FROM `question_results` AS q
INNER JOIN `user_answers`AS a ON q.question_id = a.question_id AND q.team1 = a.team1 AND q.team2 = a.team2 AND q.score1 = a.score1 AND q.score2 = a.score
```

Comment: Your answer seems ok to me,but how can i use this in eloquent way ?